# how to create maps which detect automatic location in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, gps, maps, react-native

I have created maps in react-native referring to https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps
map is created but i want to detect automatic location using gps. Here is the code which renders map with static latitude and longitude.
Here's my updated code. But it still not rendering perfect location

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        initialPosition: 'unknown',
        lastPosition: 'unknown',
    };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({initialPosition});
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({lastPosition});
    });
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref="map"
          mapType="terrain"
          style={styles.map}
          initialPosition={this.state.initialPosition}
          lastPosition={this.state.lastPosition}
        >
        </MapView>
      </View>
```

can you please correct it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using React-native geolocation: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

There is already a good example there on how you can do that:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({initialPosition});
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
  );
  this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
    this.setState({lastPosition});
  });
}
```

You now have the initialPosition (latitude and longitude), use it instead of your hard coded value. The watchPosition invokes the success callback whenever the location changes.

I am currently using this to find local restaurants in our app.

---

***Updated Answer:***

I am using Genymotion emulator to run this. If you are also going to run this code on Genymotion, please make sure you have installed **Google Play support**, otherwise react-native-maps won't work. **You don't have to do this step if you are using a physical device.**

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support

Regarding **Geolocation**, please make sure you have added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Otherwise you will get an error: "Looks like the app doesn't have the permission to access location."

*Also please make sure that your GPS/Wifi/Data is enabled, otherwise your device cannot retrieve your current location.*

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  PropTypes,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = ReactNative;

var MapView = require('react-native-maps');

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;

// (Initial Static Location) Mumbai
const LATITUDE = 19.0760;
const LONGITUDE = 72.8777;

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.01;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

var CustomMap = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      },
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
          }
        });
      },
      (error) => alert(error.message),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      const newRegion = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }

      this.onRegionChange(newRegion);
    });
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  },

  onRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ region });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref="map"
          mapType="terrain"
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        >
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.bubble}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}}>
            {`${this.state.region.latitude.toPrecision(7)}, ${this.state.region.longitude.toPrecision(7)}`}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  bubble: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    paddingHorizontal: 18,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
});

module.exports = CustomMap;
```

Running the above code, you should find that your original static location (Mumbai) is overwritten with your current location from the device through componentDidMount when getCurrentPosition is called.

If you need to track changes in position, use **watchPosition** in combination with **onRegionChange**, otherwise if you just need to get the initial position remove **watchPosition** step.

Comment: hey i have updated my code you can see it as question but the perfect location is still not rendering

Comment: are you using genymotion? Have you made sure that your GPS is enabled? Have you tried console logging position, to make sure getCurrentPosition returns a valid position? I also noticed that you are not handling errors in your getCurrentPosition call. Try adding "(error) => alert(error.message)," to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: I am using physical device to test. i have removed the error part tried adding it but no success. is my code correct?

Comment: Great to hear. Would you mind marking my answer as correct please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please answer the question on given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157354/mapview-marker-is-not-stable-on-user-current-location-moves-on-zooming-and-pinch

Comment: antoni can you tell me how to add my location button on map? it is missing on mine.

Comment: Hi, if you phrase it as a stackoverflow question with more details I can have a look at it

Comment: Does the watchPosition() update the accuracy everytime?