# MapView.Marker is not stable on user current location moves on zooming and pinching

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

Hey guys i have created a mapView in react-native now i have to set fix marker on user current location. I have obtained current location using navigator.geolocation also set the marker using MapView.Marker initially marker shows correct location but gets moved on zooming and pinching

Here is my code.

```
    getInitialState() {
    return {
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      },
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
          }
        });
      },
    );

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      const newRegion = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }

      this.onRegionChange(newRegion);
    });
  },
```

here is the render method

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref="map"
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        >
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.region}>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
```

can anybody help on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution . This is the updated code

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
          }
        });
      },
    );
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref="map"
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        >
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.region} />

        </MapView>
```

The problem was navigator.geolocation.watchPosition it was updating my new region whenever it is getting changed hence the marker was changing on region change.